# Spacing in tables

Tags: css

So I'm trying to create these three images in a table, so the Logo is in the middle and the two buttons are on the side. However, when I do so the last photo (sign up) for some reason strays allllll the way to the right and the other 2 are next to each other just fine. I believe the problem lies with the Logo because when I switch the order to: :the refer a friend, sign up, logo" it's aligned all together perfectly. However I need the logo in the middle of the two. There's really no coding to this other than the table so I'm really lost with what's happening. I tried the coding in a completely blank document in case the other coding I have interferes but like I said, it has to be the logo I'm using. There's no extra space in the logo image it's self so I really don't know how to fix this. I can only give you two of the images because I don't have the "reputation" but the sign up and refer a friend buttons are the same size just different links. But here's the HTML I'm not using any CSS.

```
<center><table>
<tr>
   <td><a href="refer.html"><img src="refer.png" width="80%"></a></td>
   <td><img id="logo" src="logo.png" width="20%"></td>
 <td><a href="signup.html"><img id="signup" src="signup.png" width="80%</a>            </td>
</tr>
</table></center>
```

[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WouE6.png)

[refer a friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEdk0.png)

Comment: <center> is depreciated in HTML5. Use CSS to center instead. Sign up button?

Comment: Why do you use table element for layout?

Answer (score 0):

First. the `center` tag is depreciated in HTML5 (Standard). Use CSS instead.

Second don't define widths in HTML, do it in CSS because you have more control.

The problem was semi-fixed by removing the % on the HTML and adding px instead. The logo was affecting the image to its right because there was white-space as seen if a background was added to the `tr`.

A better way of doing layout is using `div` and `span`

I created a codepen for you. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGpMJV

I submitted the answer accidentally while I was still trying to figure out the full anwser so refresh and this is the correct fix.